# Incidence geometry with curves instead of lines

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves, affine-geometry

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field. Say that a subset $C$ of the affine plane $K^2$ is an **irreducible curve** if there is an irreducible polynomial $f\in K[X,Y]$ (where $X$ and $Y$ are indeterminates) such that 
$$
C=\{(x,y)\in K^2\ |\ f(x,y)=0\}.
$$ 
Let $\mathcal C$ be the set of all irreducible curves, and let $\mathcal L\subset\mathcal C$ be the subset of all lines. Clearly $\mathcal L$ satisfies the four axioms at the beginning of [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_plane_(incidence_geometry)).

> Is $\mathcal L$ the only subset of $\mathcal C$ satisfying these four axioms?

To avoid any misunderstanding let me rephrase the same question in a more formal way.

Let $\Lambda$ be a subset of $\mathcal C$ such that

$\bullet$ If $a$ and $b$ are distinct points of $K^2$, then there is a unique $C\in\Gamma$ such that $a,b\in C$.

$\bullet$ Given any $C\in\Gamma$ and any $a\in K^2\setminus C$ there is a unique $C'\in\Gamma$ such that $a\in C'$ and $C\cap C'=\varnothing$.

Is $\Gamma$ necessarily equal to $\mathcal L$?

[Note that two of the four axioms have been omitted because they are trivially true in the present context.]

**EDIT** A positive answer to the above question would imply:

> If $K$ an algebraically closed field and $X$ and $Y$ are indeterminates, then $K$ can be recovered (up to isomorphism) from the topological space $\text{Spec}(K[X,Y])$.

Indeed, $K[X,Y]$ being noetherian, the topology of $\text{Spec}(K[X,Y])$ depends only on its poset structure (because any closed subset of $\text{Spec}(K[X,Y])$ is a finite union of closures of points). Moreover, this poset structure depends only on the inclusions of the form $(f)\subset(X-x,Y-y)$, where $f\in K[X,Y]$ is irreducible and $x,y\in K$. Clearly such an inclusion holds if and only if $f(x,y)=0$, that is, if and only if the point $(x,y)$ belongs to the irreducible curve defined by $f$.

In other words, the topology of $\text{Spec}(K[X,Y])$ depends only on the incidence relations between points and irreducible curves in $K^2$.

If we knew that this incidence structure depended only on the incidence relations between points and **lines** in $K^2$, we could invoke Section II.5 of Emil Artin's book **Geometric Algebra**, which shows that $K$ can be recovered (up to isomorphism) from these  incidence relations between points and lines in $K^2$.